# What happens when the target of Ensnaring Strike enters the Ethereal Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ethereal-plane

Ensnaring Strike states the following (abridged for brevity):

> The next time you hit a creature with a weapon attack before this spell ends, a writhing mass of thorny vines appears at the point of impact, and the target must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be restrained by the magical vines until the spell ends. If the target succeeds on the save, the vines shrivel away.

Ensnaring Strike has a duration of Concentration, up to 1 minute.

**What happens if the target of Ensnaring Strike enters the Ethereal Plane?** They might accomplish this through methods such as the Etherealness spell.

Specifically:

- Do the effects of the spell remain while they're in the Ethereal Plane?
- Can they pass through the vines that are holding them while in the Ethereal Plane?
- Are the effects of the spell restored when they return from the Ethereal Plane?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## The target is still restrained on the Ethereal Plane

**tl;dr** The target is still restrained because magic.

The spell effects don't end when the target travels to the ethereal plane.

Normally, the target would be able to move in any direction just as easily (see [*etherealness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/etherealness) or DMG p.48).  In this case, the target may get to the ethereal plane, but they're still restrained which makes their movement speed 0.

### Magic objects still impedes movement on the ethereal plane.

A regular solid object, such as a vine, would not normally impeded the movement of a character in the Ethereal Plane.  However, ensnaring strike makes magic vines.

Dungeon Master's Guide p. 48:

> ...solid objects on the overlapped plane don't hamper the movement of a creature in the Border Ethereal. The exceptions are certain magical effects (including anything made of magical force) and living beings.